# How to put an onclick event for a HTML table row created dynamically through java script.?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.

Can anyone help me to implement an `onclick` event on click of a HTML table row created through javascript?

Kindly note that I am inserting the data in table cells using `innerHTML`.
Below is the code snippet of what i have tried.?

**Java Script function:**

```
function addRow(msg)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("NotesFinancialSummary");
    var finSumArr1 = msg.split("^");
    var length = finSumArr1.length-1;
    alert("length"+ length);
    for(var i=1; i<finSumArr1.length; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var rowValues1 = finSumArr1[i].split("|");
        for(var k=0;k<=10;k++)
        {       
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(k);
            var element1 = rowValues1[k];
            cell1.innerHTML = element1;     
        }   


    }

        for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++)
        {
            for(var k=0;k<=10;k++)
            {   
                document.getElementById("NotesFinancialSummary").rows[i].cells[k].addEventListener("click", function(){enableProfileDiv()}, false);


            }
        }       

}
```

**HTML table code in jsp :**

```
     <TABLE id="NotesFinancialSummary" width="800px" border="1" align="left" >
<tr >

                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Claimant</th>
                <th>MJC</th>
                <th>S</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Indemnity Resv</th>
                <th>Indemnity Paid</th>
                <th>Medical Resv</th>
                <th>Medical Paid</th>
                <th>Legal Resv</th>
                <th>Legal Paid</th>
     </tr>
      <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <TD> </TD>          
                    <TD> </TD>
                    <TD> </TD>          
                    <TD> </TD>
                    <TD> </TD>          
                        <TD> </TD>
                        <TD> </TD>  
                        <TD> </TD>  
                        <TD> </TD>  
                        <TD> </TD>  
        </tr>



    </table>
```

Comment: You should post some code showing us how you're inserting the table row

Comment: Do you mean for a specific row in the table or all of them?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo please refer to the code snippet attached

Answer (score 2):

`<table id="table"></table>`

```
$("#table").append("<tr><td>Hi there</td></tr>");

$("#table").on( "click", "tr", function(){
    // do something
    alert( $(this).children("td:first").text() );
});
```

Any time the `click` event bubbles up to `<table id="table">`, this function will be called (no matter if the `<tr>`s are inserted dynamically, or hard coded).

This will require the jQuery library

- http://jquery.com/
- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: He didn't say he was using jquery, and he's new to javascript.

Comment: If the OP had posted some code, I might know what he's doing. He didn't say he's *not* using jQuery... and he is dynamically inserting rows, so there must be some understanding. But without knowing, I simply responded with one solution.

Comment: That's fine, but he crearly doesn't have a pretty good grasp of what he's doing, I think you should explaing what you're doing (at least explain that you're using a library)

Comment: it is not tagged with jQuery, therefore the solution should not contain jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be using `document.createElement`

Instead of doing:

```
yourParentElement.innerHTML = "<tr>Something</tr>";
```

You can do

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.innerHTML = "Something";
tr.onclick = function() {
    //code to be executed onclick
};
yourParentElement.appendChild(tr);
```

Another way, would be to use an `id` (**only** if you're doing this once, you don't want duplicated ids):

```
yourParentElement.innerHTML = "<tr id='someId'>Something</tr>";
document.getElementById("someId").onclick = function() { //fetch the element and set the event

}
```

You can read more about events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), but just so you have an idea `onclick` will only let you set *one* function.
If you want a better solution you can use something like [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), but it's not [crossbrowser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser) so you may want to read up on it.

Lastly, if you want to set up an event on *every* `tr` you can use:

```
var trs = document.getElementByTagName("tr"); //this returns an array of trs
//loop through the tr array and set the event
```

Answer (score 1):

after you insert your `<tr>` using innerHTML, create a click event listener for it.

```
document.getElementById("the new id of your tr").addEventListener("click", function() {
     what you want to do on click;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gnBtr/

```
var startEl = document.getElementById('start');
var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');

var inner = '<div id="content" style = "background: pink; padding:20px;" > click on me </div>'

// Function to change the content of containerEl
function modifyContents() {
  containerEl.innerHTML = inner;
  var contentEl = document.getElementById('content');
  contentEl.addEventListener("click", handleClickOnContents, false);
}

// listenting to clikc on element created via innerHTML
function handleClickOnContents() {
  alert("you clicked on a div that was dynamically created");
}

// add event listeners
startEl.addEventListener("click", modifyContents, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```
$('#your_table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $('td', this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
} );
```

css:

```
tr:hover td{
    background-color: lightsteelblue !important;
}
```

It works fine for me, specially when I'm using jquery dataTable pagination.